# Decode a json tree structure

Tags: json, reason, bucklescript

In the **bs-json** library there is an example provided for converting a json structure to a tree using the `andThen` combinator. The original example can be found [here on github](https://github.com/glennsl/bs-json/blob/b8218938959a2b20d8b6c8ee2600b75e5bdcb1cb/src/Json_decode.mli#L434-L472) in the ML interface file. Copying the function `decodeTree` from this file to the browser reason tools shows a syntax error.

Would very much appreciate any pointers for getting this to work.

My attempt at translating it to Reason3 results in a type error. This is the code:

```
type tree('a) =
  | Node('a, list(tree('a)))
  | Leaf('a);

let json = {| {
  "type": "node",
  "value": 9
  "children": [{
    "type": "leaf",
    "value": 5,
    "children": [{
      "type": "leaf",
      "value": 3
    }, {
      "type": "leaf",
      "value": 2
    }]
  }, {
      "type": "leaf",
      "value": 4
  }]
} |};

let decodeTree = (decodeValue, json) =>
  Json.Decode.(
    field("type", string)
    |> andThen(type_ =>
         switch type_ {
         | "node" =>
           Node(
             field("value", decodeValue),
             field("children", children =>
               children |> array(decodeTree) |> map(Array.to_list)
             )
           )
         | "leaf" => Leaf(field("value", decodeValue))
         }
       )
  );

let myTree = json |> Json.parseOrRaise |> decodeTree(Json.Decode.int);
```

This is the type error,

```
This has type:
   tree('a)
But somewhere wanted:
   Json.Decode.decoder('b) (defined as (Js.Json.t) => 'b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that. Not entirely sure what was going on with that example. Here's one that should work:

```javascript
/* Decode a JSON tree structure */
type tree('a) =
  | Node('a, list(tree('a)))
  | Leaf('a);

module Decode = {
  open Json.Decode;

  let rec tree = decoder =>
    field("type", string) |> andThen(
       fun | "node" => node(decoder)
           | "leaf" => leaf(decoder)
           | _      => failwith("unknown node type")
     )

  and node = (decoder, json) =>
    Node(
      json |> field("value", decoder),
      json |> field("children", array(tree(decoder)) |> map(Array.to_list))
    )

  and leaf = (decoder, json) =>
    Leaf(json |> field("value", decoder));
};

let json = {| {
  "type": "node",
  "value": 9,
  "children": [{
    "type": "node",
    "value": 5,
    "children": [{
      "type": "leaf",
      "value": 3
    }, {
      "type": "leaf",
      "value": 2
    }]
  }, {
      "type": "leaf",
      "value": 4
  }]
} |};

let myTree =
  json |> Json.parseOrRaise
       |> Decode.tree(Json.Decode.int);
```

**Edit**: The specific error you have is caused by `andThen` expecting a decoder, but being given a `tree('a)` (`Node` or `Leaf`). All that's needed to turn it into a decoder is to add a json argument, which you'd pass to the field decoders:

```
|> andThen((type_, json) =>
     switch type_ {
     | "node" =>
       Node(
         json |> field("value", decodeValue),
         json |> field("children", children =>
           children |> array(decodeTree) |> map(Array.to_list)
         )
       )
     | "leaf" => json |> Leaf(field("value", decodeValue))
     }
   )
```